# Select or export features within layer that intersect one another, and also within distance in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select-by-location

As shown in the image, I would like to select or export features within a layer that intersect one another, and also within a specified distance.

[image]

I am trying to use the "Select Layer by Location" tool, but it is selecting all the features.

How do I do this in ArcMap?

Comment: If you also want to know how to do this in QGIS then feel free to ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand correctly, I would use a [buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) instead using half the distance and dissolving adjacent buffers (if you buffer each polygon by half the distance when two or more polygons are near another the sum will equal the full distance). Then, use a [spatial join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) on your buffer using the input polygons to get the count of the number of input polygons that intersect each buffer. Then [attribute query](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-attributes.htm) any buffer that has a count of >1 input polygons associated with it.  Then finally, [select by location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) the input polygons that intersect your queried buffer layer.